# Using AngularJS with MVC SelectList has no value initially selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I have a class that has an MVC SelectList and an int that indicates the selected value.

```
public class SampleClass {
      public SelectList ServicesAvailable {get; set;}
      public int ServiceIdSelected {get; set;}

      public SampleClass() {}
}
```

When you go to the page to edit the item you expect that the item you previously selected is selected to begin with. Using razor @Html.DropDownListFor(...) this works absolutely fine. However, this page is using Angular and so I am using:

```
<select style="width:40%;" chosen data-placeholder="Select a method" 
     no-results-text="'No service found'" ng-model="ServiceIdSelected" 
     ng-options="item.Value as item.Text for item in ServicesAvailable">
        <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Using this Angular annotation the initial item is never selected. I can only think that this is because the Value and Text properties of the MVC SelectList are both strings and that Angular is doing something like ServiceIdSelected === item.Value  in the background and since one is a string and the other an int it is always false.

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, how did you get around it?  Is my only option to change the SelectList property to a List<> of something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could checkout this fiddle maybe this helps you.

```
<select 
            ng-model="Choice.SelectedOption"                 
            ng-options="choice.Name for choice in Choice.Options track by choice.ID"></select>
```

[Fiddle for select](http://jsfiddle.net/gFCzV/34/)

Cheers Christopher,

Comment: Hmm, so rather than using an integer in the model I could use an object . So to map back to the view model on post it would have to be a SelectListItem instead.

Comment: So, what I did instead was use a string for ServiceIdSelected as there is a unique string property on a Service. Saves trying to post an extra object and keeps it simple.